# barra de progresso em python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando montar uma barra de progresso para dizer a porcentagem da execução do meu script Python com varia funções diferentes, porem sem sucesso como eu criaria tal barra de progresso?

Comment: O que você já tentou? Tem algum código que tenha funcionado parcialmente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a lib [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm), ela é própria para isso e seu uso é extremamente simles, veja um exemplo:

```
>>> from tqdm import tqdm
>>> from time import sleep
>>> for i in tqdm(range(1000)):
...     sleep(0.01)
```

Basta você passar um iteravel para a função `tqdm` e a progress bar será criada automaticamente. 
Existem outras formas de trabalhar com essa lib, de uma olhada na [documentação](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#documentation)